# Can't find change history for code in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my C# course, I noticed I received docked points for my project not having code change history. After looking around, I couldn't figure out what it was about. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise with no external plug-ins. My professor has also not mentioned anywhere on our course site about installing extra features, so I assumed this change history for code would have been a build in feature to reduce students from being required extra setup.

All I've actually found in VS itself is a window called "History" under `View > Other Windows`, however, that is empty and shows no indication of allowing me to use it. Hopefully this isn't considered a duplicate post considering the few other "change history" questions that only resulted in 3rd party or extra installation features; I don't think those are what I need here. My professor lists the need for code change history, yet I can't seem to figure out how to do that with the IDE itself, which is the only software we're expected to work with.

Am I just at a loss of assignment points on this one?

Comment: Did you ask the professor to explain what it is and what is expected?

Comment: Are you using version control tools, such as Git, svn ... ?

Comment: No control tools such as Git, etc. None of that stuff was listed in our required tools for the course. I will, of course, email my professor about this, but at the moment, it's 12am and I'm currently at a loss on this since it affects an assignment I'm working on. Considering I won't get an immediate response from the professor, here is reasonable and timely forum to ask.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019#find-changes-in-your-code)

Comment: I definitely did see that article during my research, but I put it on the back-burner because I'm still hung on the fact that my professor never listed any of those services or features as being required to setup in our IDE environments. If that's truly the only way to see change history of the code, then I'm not quite sure what my professor wants. But since I now know of a few different options available, I can specifically ask about them to my professor. Honestly shouldn't even have to inquire this stuff if the professor just gave full information to begin with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using a version control system then each check in / commit  should have a description of the change.
2. Before we used version control systems (over 20 years ago) we had a section at the end of the source file with comments for each change made, which version and date.

If I was a professor I would not expect the students to send me their code, I would ask them to put their code in a repo such as git and then send me a link to the repo.